# How I can create new transaction in safe from my DAPP without conencting Safe address to dapp with wallet-connect?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Description of my preferred flow:
I have 3 admins in my Safe. One of them connect to my dapp website through wallet connect with OWN address, not with Safe address. Its important part. After this my admin can ability to work with my smart-contract. He can choose one of contract methods and can sign this transaction with own wallet. But all this methods can be executed only with Safe wallet. How to send this data to the Safe, so that other admins approve it, sign and send to the blockchain?
Can you describe what logic I can implement? Maybe after admin choose action I can send this data to Safe via specific API? Or maybe there is another ways?